# Error: No provider for Store! when trying @ngrx/store with Angular 4.0

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Problem:
**Error: No provider for Store!**

I'm bootstraping store module in main.ts:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,[
  provideStore({
    characters, 
    vehicles
  })
]);
```

And injecting in to vehicle.component.ts:

```
constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _vehicleService: VehicleService,
    private _store: Store<any>
  ) {}
```

Full source code is here: [GitHub](https://github.com/antonpegov/angular-fl/tree/1934bd1656c298074ae005e2d03c07ee9dfc7a2f),
last version running [on GitHub Pages](https://antonpegov.github.io/angular-fl)

PS. Adding Store to providers leads to another error:
Can't resolve all parameters for Store: (?, ?, ?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `app.module.ts` add:

```
// Make sure you import from @ngrx/store
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      StoreModule.forRoot({ characters, vehicles }),
  ...
```

Comment: Should we pass the real reducers? As its just component testing

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the answer was to fix a provider error. But for testing purposes I don't see why not to pass the actual reducers.

Answer (score 14):

I had this error because, in my component auto-import imported `Store` from 
`import { Store } from '@ngrx/store/src/store'` instead of 
`import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'`; . Anyway, this was in Angular 5

Comment: Just had the same issue and didn't even notice it! Thanks for this post, you saved me some time :)

Comment: thanks, for some reason my auto import imported store from `ngrx/store`

Answer (score 6):

Just for sake of completeness, with Angular 5 / Ngrx 4.1.1 it would be (in app.module.ts):

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './reducers/reducers';

@NgModule({
    imports: [     
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
        ...
    ],
    ...
```

There is a complete example [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/ngrx/ngrx-store-4-angular-5-tutorial)